# How to remove ok button qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I need simple toastr message so I want to remove ok buttom from QMessageBox.

My code:

```
    QMessageBox* msgbox = new QMessageBox(this);
    msgbox->setGeometry(850, 450, 250, 200);
    msgbox->setWindowTitle("Error");
    msgbox->setText(msg);
    msgbox->open();
    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), msgbox, SLOT(close()));
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), timer, SLOT(stop()));
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), timer, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    timer->start(1000);
```

Comment: Create your own widget for that. I doubt you can hide OK button in QMessageBox.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmessagebox.html#QMessageBox-1

Comment: Your msgbox->open() compiles without arguments?

Comment: @ÖöTiib, no compilation problem there, `QMessageBox` has the `open` public slot inherited from `QDialog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
auto msgbox = new QMessageBox(this);
msgbox->setGeometry(850, 450, 250, 200);
msgbox->setWindowTitle("Error");
msgbox->setText(msg);
msgbox->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::NoButton);
msgbox->open();
auto timer = new QTimer(msgbox);
QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, msgbox, &QMessageBox::deleteLater);
timer->start(1000);
```

note the use of `setStandardButtons()` which actually removes the button. But as I found, then method `close()` does not work so I had to replace it with `deleteLater()`. This also solves the bug in your code: you never deleted the message box, you only closed it.

I also replaced old-style of connections with the new style. You should never ever use the old style any more and you should discourage everybody from using it. The new style is significantly superior because they allow for compile time type checks.

I also made some more changes: the timer became child of the message box. Then it will be deleted automatically with the message box. And also the connection to `stop()` slot is not needed.

PS: I also feel that you are misusing `QMessageBox` for something for which it was not designed. Check class `QSplashScreen`, maybe it will suit better to your needs.